# Missing page numbers with elsarticle

Tags: page-numbering, elsarticle

I am using a template for a preprint article to be reviewed, but the page number is missing, I would like it on the bottom centre of the page. With other formats different to elsarticle It seems to work but everything else is messed up.

```
\documentclass[3p,,preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\makeatletter\if@twocolumn\PassOptionsToPackage{switch}{lineno}\else\fi\makeatother

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tabulary,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\let\save@ps@pprintTitle\ps@pprintTitle
\def\ps@pprintTitle{\save@ps@pprintTitle\gdef\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape \null\hfill\today}}
\def\hlinewd#1{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1%
  \futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\def\tbltoprule{\hlinewd{.8pt}\\[-12pt]}
\def\tblbottomrule{\noalign{\vspace*{6pt}}\hline\noalign{\vspace*{2pt}}}
\def\tblmidrule{\noalign{\vspace*{6pt}}\hline\noalign{\vspace*{2pt}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\ifNAT@numbers \biboptions{sort&compress}\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
\else 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi 
\ifluatex\else\usepackage{stmaryrd}\fi

  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Following additional macros are required to function some 
% functions which are not available in the class used.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url,multirow,morefloats,floatflt,cancel,tfrupee}
\makeatletter


\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\urlstyle{rm}
\makeatletter

%%%For Table column width calculation.
\def\mcWidth#1{\csname TY@F#1\endcsname+\tabcolsep}

%%Hacking center and right align for table
\def\cAlignHack{\rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue\parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
\def\rAlignHack{\rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}

%Etal definition in references
\@ifundefined{etal}{\def\etal{\textit{et~al}}}{}


%\if@twocolumn\usepackage{dblfloatfix}\fi
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex\else\if@twocolumn\@ifpackageloaded{stfloats}{}{\usepackage{dblfloatfix}}\fi\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
\expandafter\ifx\csname eqalign\endcsname\relax
\def\eqalign#1{\null\vcenter{\def\\{\cr}\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
\fi
}

%For fixing hardfail when unicode letters appear inside table with endfloat
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}%
   {\renewcommand\efloat@iwrite[1]{\immediate\expandafter\protected@write\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}}{\newif\ifefloat@tables}%
}%

\def\BreakURLText#1{\@tfor\brk@tempa:=#1\do{\brk@tempa\hskip0pt}}
\let\lt=<
\let\gt=>
\def\processVert{\ifmmode|\else\textbar\fi}
\let\processvert\processVert

\@ifundefined{subparagraph}{
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{2\parindent}{0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}%
{0ex}{\normalfont\small\itshape}}%
}{}

% These are now gobbled, so won't appear in the PDF.
\newcommand\role[1]{\unskip}
\newcommand\aucollab[1]{\unskip}
  
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleX}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleX{1}}{}
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleY}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleY{.9}}{}
% To automatically resize figures to fit inside the text area
\def\checkGraphicsWidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \tsGraphicsScaleX\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}

\def\checkGraphicsHeight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>.9\textheight
    \tsGraphicsScaleY\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}

\def\fixFloatSize#1{}%\@ifundefined{processdelayedfloats}{\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}\ifnum\wd0<\columnwidth\relax\renewenvironment{figure*}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}\fi}{}}
\let\ts@includegraphics\includegraphics

\def\inlinegraphic[#1]#2{{\edef\@tempa{#1}\edef\baseline@shift{\ifx\@tempa\@empty0\else#1\fi}\edef\tempZ{\the\numexpr(\numexpr(\baseline@shift*\f@size/100))}\protect\raisebox{\tempZ pt}{\ts@includegraphics{#2}}}}

%\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth]{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[{\ts@includegraphics}{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth,height=\checkGraphicsHeight,keepaspectratio]}}}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\def\URL#1#2{\@ifundefined{href}{#2}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

%%For url break
\def\UrlOrds{\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}

%       BIBLIOGRAPHY PACKAGES
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = numeric-comp, sorting = none, maxnames=100]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\edef\fntEncoding{\f@encoding}
\def\EUoneEnc{EU1}
\makeatother
\def\floatpagefraction{0.8} 
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{0.8}
\def\style#1#2{#2}
\def\xxxguillemotleft{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotleft}
\def\xxxguillemotright{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotright}

\newif\ifmultipleabstract\multipleabstractfalse%
\newenvironment{typesetAbstractGroup}{}{}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\emergencystretch 20pt \tolerance = 1500 \def\floatpagefraction{0.8}




    \makeatletter
\def\ead{\@ifnextchar[{\@uad}{\@ead}}
\gdef\@ead#1{\bgroup
   \def\_{\string\underscorechar\space}
   \def\{{\string\lbracechar\space}
   \def\textdagger{\string\textdagger\space}
   \def\texttildeapprox{\string\texttildeapprox\space}
   \def~{\hashchar\space}
   \def\}{\string\rbracechar\space}
   \edef\tmp{\the\@eadauthor}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\emailauthor
     {#1}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmp}}
  \egroup
}
%\newcounter{ead}
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2{\stepcounter{ead}
      \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright
      \let\corref\@gobble
      \eadsep\texttt{#1} (#2)
      \def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}
}

\makeatother
  
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. Your question is impossible to answer just from the `\documentclass`.

Comment: If you are submitting to an else*ier journal, ask the publisher. If not, use a different document class....

Comment: @JamesT Ok I tried to include all the settings of the template. Let me know if you need sth else...

Comment: @AlessandroGiustina -- Did you even try the code you posted?